# Write script for GitLab for automatic merge of Merge Request

Tags: python, shell, rest, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to write a script to merge the merge requests which are open and have met the criteria of merge requests (which is achieved via settings).

So the only thing I want to do is, I want to write a CI yaml file which I will schedule to run every 30 minutes or so to check for open merge request and merge them if they can be merged.

Confusion One:

I am able to achieve this via writing multiple curl requests, but I am not sure how to make use of them one after another after their execution.

So, to check for the open merge requests, I will need the ID of the projects of a group, to get that I have a curl command which will provide me project ids and I am saving them in a file `projectid.txt`.

```
curl -s --location --request GET --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN:<PRIVATE_TOKEN>' '$CI_API_V4_URL/groups/'$GROUPID'/projects'  | sed 's/,/\n/g' | grep -w "id" | awk -F ':' '{print $2}' | sed -s 's/{"id"//g'
```

Now, Once I have all the project ids,
I want to flow them into another curl command which is :

```
curl -s --location --request GET '$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/3/merge_requests?state=opened' --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN:<PRIVATE_TOKEN>' | sed 's/,/\n/g' | grep -w "iid" | awk -F ':' '{print $2}'
```

but if you see the above curl request, I am giving `3` manually to get the desired output.

But I want this curl command to automatically take every projectid present in every line of `projectid.txt` and execute it to the second curl command.. In this way I want a file which will display the open merge request project wise.

Once I get all these information, I want to merge the open merge requests which are valid and are ready to be merged (GitLab takes care of checking if they are ready to merge or not)

So, the only thing I need now is, to give input of `projectid` & `merge request id` in the another curl command which is a PUT request.

```
curl --location --request PUT '$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/3/merge_requests/26/merge' \
--header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: <PRIVATE_TOKEN>'
```

Source: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#accept-mr

If you see the above merge request, I need to provide project wise merge requests.. I am kind of confused on how it can be automated.

Also, Can you tell me if this is a correct way to make use of these many curl requests in my `gitlab-ci.yml` file to automate this? Is there any other way to do it via `Python` or shell script?

Also, Is there any easy way to write python scripts with the help of REST APIs documentation ? I am able to generate curl requests to play with the REST APIs but not sure how it could be achieved with Python.

Any help or suggestions are most welcome.

My gitlab-ci.yml file looks like this till now as I am not able to think much after this point:

```
variables:
  GROUPID: 6
stages:
  - cleanup

cleanup-code-job:
  stage: cleanup
  tags:
    - build
  script:
    - echo "$GROUPID"
    ##Below curl command can be used to identify projects in group
    - curl -s --location --request GET --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN:<PRIVATE_TOKEN>' '$CI_API_V4_URL/groups/'$GROUPID'/projects'  | sed 's/,/\n/g' | grep -w "id" | awk -F ':' '{print $2}' | sed -s 's/{"id"//g' > projects.txt
    - cat projects.txt
```

Thanks

Comment: did you have a look at the marge-bot?

Comment: No @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann! Let me check it, Can you also give me little context about it.?

Comment: Marge can - besides other nice features like implementing the `not rocket science rule of software development` - merge MRs when they are green and having been reviewed. https://github.com/smarkets/marge-bot

Comment: After going through the documentation, Looks like I will need to create a user which will take up a seat. :(

Comment: For Marge? Yes, that's true. If you script something yourself the answer will depend on if you are allowed to run this script with your own user credentials or need to have separation of privileges. (Which I would prefer, honestly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [`python-gitlab` library](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html), a python script makes this task a lot simpler to script, especially when it comes to pagination.

Additionally, you can use the [Group merge requests API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#list-group-merge-requests) as a shortcut instead of listing all projects in the group then listing all merge requests in each project.

With a Python script, it might look something like this:

```py
import gitlab
from gitlab.v4.objects import GroupMergeRequest
TOKEN = "your API key"
GITLAB_HOST = 'https://gitlab.com' # or your instance
gl = gitlab.Gitlab(GITLAB_HOST, private_token=TOKEN)

GROUP_ID = 123

def mr_meets_merge_criteria(mr: GroupMergeRequest) -> bool:
    """
    A function to check if it meets criteria to
    be merged automatically by this script
    """
    print(mr.project_id)
    print(mr.merge_status)  # e.g. 'can_be_merged'
    # check something
    ...
    return True | False

group = gl.groups.get(GROUP_ID)

# loop over all merge requests in the group
for mr in group.mergerequests.list(as_list=False):
    if mr_meets_merge_criteria(mr):
        project = gl.projects.get(mr.project_id, lazy=True)
        project_mr = project.mergerequests.get(mr.iid)
        project_mr.merge()
```

So, if you input the correct constants and complete the implementation of the `mr_meets_merge_criteria` function, that should be all that is needed :-)

Comment: Hi @sytech , this is something extremely helpful. I will explore on this package and make use of it. Also, One error I found when I tried to execute the script which you provided. 
Looks like their is some error in the line  `def mr_meets_merge_criteria(mr: GroupMergeRequest) -> bool:` as it says `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`  on `->`Are you sure that it works for you ?

Comment: Make sure you're using a recent version of Python3 -- or you can remove the type hinting syntax for older versions of Python3 like `def mr_meets_merge_criteria(mr):` @SameerAtharkar

Comment: Okay it worked now. One more small query @sytech I am exploring different things now. I never used it actually . So I am trying different things like displaying project ids, users in project.. and branches in the project. Can you tell me how can I pass the details of branches ? I used `users = gl.users.list()` & `print(users)` and it was working, but when I tried to display `branches = project.branches.list()` It said `name 'project' is not defined` Can you tell me how can I pass the project id here?

Comment: Sounds like a general programming error, perhaps better suited for a separate question on its own @SameerAtharkar if you still need help -- it sounds like you failed to define a `project` variable. But in general, you can retrieve projects like `project = gl.projects.get("<Project path or ID number>")`. Also, as a quick important tip: to fully paginate lists in the python-gitlab API, you want to pass `as_list=False` to `.list` methods! Otherwise you'll only get the first list of results. If my answer answered your original question, please consider accepting it :-)

Comment: Okay thanks @sytech. I am wondering if I can find some basic documentation which starts from 0 or some video to explain all this. Are you aware of that? I am finding the documentation as little difficult actually. Your Answer is extremely helpful to get done the work but I am not able to understand it.